# Force path sub.domain.com/file.jpg instead of domain.com/sub/file.jpg

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, subdomain

Is this possible?

I use: WP latest version (3.3.2) and Cpanel Followed this tutorial to accomplish this: rsatechnologies.in/serve-image-media-files-from-cookie-less-domain.html

I've just managed to move all my post images in a "cookieless subdomain" and serve them in this format (path) when a user accesses the post: **img.domain.com/year/month/file.jpg** (1)

Now all my old images have this format but everytime I create a new post and upload an image, the image path shown is this: **domain.com/img/year/month/file.jpg** (2)

So what I'm trying to do is to force the site/server to use (1) instead of (2).

I've already tried everything in Media Settings tab, the only thing working is to write in the "Store uploads in this folder" and "Full path to files" fields the subdomain name ("img" that is).

Any suggestions?

I'm thinking is a Cpanel setting I'm doing wrong.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The instruction posted here http://www.jafaloo.com/2011/09/11/host-your-wordpress-images-on-subdomain-for-better-page-loading/ is good. I have all my images at http://images.freedomwall.net/year/month/image.png instead of www.freedomwall.net/wp-content/uploads/year/month/image.png